# Intellij Idea HTTP Request Payload Variable

Tags: intellij-idea, httprequest

**PROBLEM** Intellij Idea HTTP-request POST has payload values dependent on an environment. Variables are not substituted when used in a payload as they are in place of path variables, for example.

> JSON decoding error: Unrecognized token 'test': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'test': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')\n at [Source: (io.netty.buffer.ByteBufInputStream)

**RESEARCH** https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/http-client-reference.html

http-client.env.json

```
{
 "LOCAL": {
  "protocol": "http://",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": ":8000",
  "apiKey": "api-key",
  "username": "test.user@example.com",
  "password": "password"
  }
}
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/OKzE8pP.png]

- Intellij 2021.2.1
- you can select payload variables from context menu and navigate with Ctrl + click

**QUESTION** Is there a way to use variables in a payload?

Comment: There is an example of it: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/exploring-http-syntax.html#example-working-with-environment-files Can you provide more context? Which IDE version do you use? When environment files are stored? Can you navigate to something from `{{username}}` with `ctrl/cmd + click`?

Comment: I have provided some additional information.

Answer (score 3):

After playing some time and rereading the exception, I've had a guess to wrap it into double quotes. Now it works:

[image]